# Asignar un background-color según categoría

Tags: php, css, color, joomla3, background

Estoy intentando editar un PHP de un complemento Joomla, para que el color del fondo donde aparece la fecha responda al color de la categoría.
Eso se aplica en la presentación de calendario del complemento, por lo cual intenté replicarlo en el PHP de la presentación Timeline pero no funciona.
Adjunto ambos PHP y un captura dónde marco el espacio dónde quiero que el color de fondo se defina por el color de cada categoría.

Este es el código de timeline.php (dónde quiero hacer que el color de fondo sea según el color de la categoría)

```
        <div class="eb-category-<?php echo $event->category_id; ?> eb-event-container<?php if ($event->featured) echo ' eb-featured-event'; ?>">
            <div class="eb-event-date-container">
                <div class="eb-event-date <?php echo $btnInverseClass; ?>", style="background: #<?php echo $category->color_code; ?>">
```

Este es el código de calendar.php dónde se aplica un fondo según el fondo definido por la categoría:

```
<span class="eb-category-legend-color" style="background: #<?php echo $category->color_code; ?>"></span>
```

La parte del código que tomé fue "style="background: #color_code; ?>" y las definiciones de variables que encontré. Supongo que me falta definir alguna variable o colocarla en otra posición.
Espero puedan ayudarme.
GRACIAS!

Comment: Hola Santiago, esta pregunta ha sido marcada como muy extensa por la comunidad. Las preguntas que son muy extensas tienden a ser muy amplias y deben concretarse para que sea más fácil ayudar a responderlas. En este caso parece que se debe a la gran cantidad de código que hay. Ahora mismo hay 500+ líneas de PHP, ¿podría reducirse el código compartido? Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve] y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el funcionamiento general del sitio.

Comment: Ok, ahí lo resumo. GRACIAS!